# How to add static block to home page not wrapped in classes?

Tags: magento2, css, static-block

I am trying to add http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ to my Magento 2 home page. I was going to add the code in the header and the slides in a static block.

I have created a static block with the slides in there. My problem is it does not go full width because there is a div surrounding it with class="widget block block-static-block".

How can I remove those classes from the static block?

Or is there an easier way to do this that I am not thinking of? I am using 2.2.3 commerce.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the block from a widget and place it about the main content.

This is the code I used-
    
        
            
                
                    slider